# How to post data in cordova app using php and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mongodb, cordova

I am new in cordova app. I want to ask you about how to post data from a form in cordova application using php and MongoDB. I have the index.html in cordova app and comment.php in c:/xampp/htdocs. I want to display data in comment.php from index.html. Here the code. that are the index.html and comment.php

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title> 
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" /> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script>
            $.ajax({ 
                type : "POST", 
                url : "comment.php", 
                crossDomain: true,
                beforeSend : function() {$.mobile.loading('show')}, 
                complete : function() {$.mobile.loading('hide')}, 
                data : {email : 'email', comment : 'comment'}, 
                dataType : 'json', 
                success : function(response) { 
                    //console.error(JSON.stringify(response)); 
                    alert('Works!');
                }, 
                error : function() { 
                    //console.error("error"); 
                    alert('Not working!'); 
                } 
            }); 
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener( "deviceready", function () {
                new kendo.mobile.Application( document.body, {
                    statusBarStyle: "black-translucent"
                });
            }, false );
        </script>
        <div data-role="page" id="index"> 
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header"> 
                <h1>Index page</h1> 
            </div> 
            <div data-role="content"> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

comment.php

```
  $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    echo $email; 
    $comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : '';
    echo $comment;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cordova doesn't support `PHP` files only `HTML` and `Javascript`. So if you want to take `mongodb` as your default database you need to use a `REST Service` (in javascript) which points to an online api (maybe php) that handels the data requests for your mongodb (installed on the online server) and deliver the informations to your app.

if you like a database integrated into your app then you can use `SQLlite` Databases and take a look here.

https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

Answer (score 0):

In Commandline check your IP

**ipconfig**

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::19a7:4cc9:c1e8:f9ef%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192..168.one.three 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255 .255 .254 .0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192 .168 .1 .1
```

Now your server ip will be **192.168.1.3**

you can access you're `c:/xampp/htdocs/comments.php` using http://192.168.one.three/comments.php inside phonegap application. But if computer and mobile in the same network.

Phonegap itself create a server(localhost) inside the android application(apk).

Note: 192..168.one.three === 192.168.1.3

```
  <script>
            $.ajax({ 
                type : "POST", 
                url : "http://192.168.1.3/comment.php", 
                crossDomain: true,
                beforeSend : function() {$.mobile.loading('show')}, 
                complete : function() {$.mobile.loading('hide')}, 
                data : {email : 'email', comment : 'comment'}, 
                dataType : 'json', 
                success : function(response) { 
                    //console.error(JSON.stringify(response)); 
                    alert('Works!');
                }, 
                error : function() { 
                    //console.error("error"); 
                    alert('Not working!'); 
                } 
            }); 
        </script>
```